# How to make later earlier content flow after later content using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have some unchangeable HTML of the form: https://jsfiddle.net/1ajkwdx3/1/

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

#bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="foo">
    foo
  </div>
  <div id="bar">
    bar
    </bar>
</body>
```

The divs are currently absolutely positioned with `#foo` having a greater CSS `top` value than `#bar`.  Thus their order is reversed.

Is it possible (using just CSS) to keep this reversed order, but with `#foo` naturally flowing under `#bar` so that it adjusts to large content in `#bar`  (without changing the HTML) ?

Comment: Why don't you use flex? Is it something you want to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it via flex.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#bar {
  width: 50px;
}

#foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="foo">
    foo
  </div>
  <div id="bar">
    barasdf ads fasdf asdf asdf asdf
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), but support is poor for IE. You can use `box-ordinal-group` to control the specific display order of each element in a similar manner to how `z-index` to controls the stack order.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="foo">
      foo
   </div>
   <div id="bar">
      bar
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -moz-box-orient: vertical;
   box-orient: vertical;
}

#foo {
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
   box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

#bar {
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
   box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
```

See the [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rossupfield/6w3xax40/1/).